# how can i solve memory issue with imageWithContentsoffile function in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uibutton, uiimage

I am facing memory issue when adding a `UIButton` to a `UITableView`. Below is my code for setting the `UIButton`'s image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But when I use `imageName:` method instead of `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method it's working perfectly. Does anybody have good solution for this issue?

Comment: What is the "memory issue"? Does using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` make you fall in amnesia?

Comment: live bytes increasing when i set image multiple times in UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**imageWithContentsOfFile:** vs **imageNamed:**

As per my knowledge,

**imageNamed** loads the image in a special system cache, and then future calls with that image path will return the image in the cache instead of reloading it from disk.

**imageWithContentsOfFile** simply loads the image at the path you specify, but does no caching. Multiple calls to imageWithContentsOfFile for the same image will result in multiple copies in memory.

AND about memory leaks i am not sure which one is better from both to use while using large number of images in programming...